# Error 422 on uploading rackspace cloudfiles static large object

Tags: php, rest, upload, rackspace-cloud, rackspace-cloudfiles

In reference to this: http://docs.rackspace.com/files/api/v1/cf-devguide/content/Uploading_the_Manifest-d1e2227.html

so I uploaded the following JSON via PUT command on Rackspace:

Body:

```
[
    {
        "path": "/archive5/8b98fb0bc6f8694d07a1bc851b58f72a",
        "etag": "8b98fb0bc6f8694d07a1bc851b58f72a",
        "size_bytes": 20971520
    },
    {
        "path": "/archive5/c234d0f0204f67340fb4741bdf9f5e92",
        "etag": "c234d0f0204f67340fb4741bdf9f5e92",
        "size_bytes": 8382711
    }
]
```

> URL: https://storage101.ord1.clouddrive.com/v1/MossoCloudFS_hashhash/archive5/606f95dbf0a17bd7d5de202f3aab98c7?multipart-manifest=put
>
> Method: PUT
>
> Headers
>
> ETag: 606f95dbf0a17bd7d5de202f3aab98c7
>   Content-Type: application/octet-stream
>   Content-Length: 266
>   X-Auth-Token: theAuthToken
>   X-Auth-Project-Id: theProjectId

but then Cloudfiles would then return

> Problem saving/updating object
>   [[https://storage101.ord1.clouddrive.com/v1/MossoCloudFS_hashhash/archive5/606f95dbf0a17bd7d5de202f3aab98c7]](https://storage101.ord1.clouddrive.com/v1/MossoCloudFS_hashhash/archive5/606f95dbf0a17bd7d5de202f3aab98c7%5d)
>   HTTP status [422] response [
>
> ## Unprocessable
>   Entity
>
> Unable to process the contained instructions
>
> ]

What did I do wrong? I've verified that the files in the JSON body indeed exist and that they have the correct path/etag(md5) and filesize...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [php-opencloud](http://php-opencloud.com/) to do this? There's an [upload-large-object.php](https://github.com/rackspace/php-opencloud/blob/master/samples/ObjectStore/upload-large-object.php) that takes care of all of the details for you.